# What happens of Program.Main when an ASP.NET Core application is run on IISIntegration?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm developing an ASP.NET Core application that will be hosted behind IIS using IISIntegration. In the past, I've already developed a few ASP.NET Core apps, but all of them have been hosted in a Windows service, with IIS acting as a reverse proxy through URL rewriting. Now instead I have to use AspNetCoreModule.

I'm wondering what happens to `Program.Main()`. Specifically, I call EntityFrameworkCore's `EnsureCreated()` there, before building the web host. However, even though my application launches correctly and even responds to requests, the database was not populated with the necessary tables.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I would move ensure created from main to startup or even deeper. After having a similar problem i moved it to the configure method of the startup class so i know it will always fire. And i used `db.Database.Migrate();` to ensure that all of my migrations are executed as well further in the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since there is a bit more to it i decided to add the rest of the code i used for it

```
var scopeFactory = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>();
        using (var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            var db = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DbContext>();
            db.Database.Migrate();
        }
```

Comment: Thank you - this works! Just a question: my model change was not applied to the database schema. Shouldn't `db.Database.Migrate()` have done exactly that?

Comment: yes it should. how many migrations do you have maybe some of them have an error or they are changing database fields for which you need to change the setting on auto migrations to true  in order to bypass truncation checks among others. i would manually call from cli all migrations and see if they will pass or not. if they all pass then log every step from the database server side to see where it breaks

Comment: My fault: I hadn't created any migrations, but I somehow expected the model to be transfered to my database (much like if I dropped the database then run `EnsureCreated()`). Thank you!